# FloatBarrier starting a new page

Tags: tables, floats, bibliographies, page-breaking

I have a document with a large list of tables that should appear, in order, in an appendix before the bibliography/references. Initially I had a problem with tables appearing all over the place in my document, in the middle of previous sections, in the middle of the bibliography, etc. I solved this by using `\FloatBarrier` before my bibliography and by using `[ht]` on each of my tables. This is fine when I only have a couple tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{placeins}

\newcommand{\testtable}{\begin{table}[ht]
    \tiny
    \caption {PSNR Comparison}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc}
        \hline \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} \\
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} \\
        \hline \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}
\blindtext

\section*{Appendix A}
\blindtext

\section*{Appendix B}
\testtable
\testtable

\FloatBarrier
\section*{References}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I add more tables than can fit on a page, suddenly the bibliography ends up on its own page when it could easily fit on the previous page (add five more `\testtable`s to see this):

[image]

How do I get the references to appear on the third page after the last table?

Comment: by using `[ht]` you are restricting the places the float can go so making it more likely that it can not be positioned so will drift to the end of the docuemnt. `\FloafBarrier` either does nothing (if there are no pending floats) or does `\clearpage` (if there are) so it always forces a new page if it does anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your appendix is just a list of tables, you don't really want them to float at all, simplest way to change them to being non-floats is to use `H` from the float package, (which is often over-used but works OK here)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\testtable}{\begin{table}[H]
    \tiny
    \caption {PSNR Comparison}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc}
        \hline \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{F} \\
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} &
        \textit{Rate} & \textit{PSNR} \\
        \hline \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
        x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}
\blindtext

\section*{Appendix A}
\blindtext

\section*{Appendix B}
\testtable
\testtable
\testtable
\testtable
\testtable
\testtable
\testtable


\section*{References}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```