# Is there any way to force the bibliography in the end without pagebreaks?

Tags: bibliographies, floats, natbib

So I have the following problem: I have a bunch of floats that have not been placed yet before the bibliography starts;

If I don't do anything about it, I get the bibliography and then afterwards the remaining floats; However, I want the bibliography last;

Typical, you would do something like

```
\FloatBarrier
```

or

```
\clearpage
```

directly before

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{bib}
```

which puts all the remaining figures in front of the bibliography - however, it also performs a page break which gives me a page that is 80% empty;
How can I avoid it?

I searched online but only found incorrect answers, see e.g. here

[Clearpage without pagebreak?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88657/clearpage-without-pagebreak)

All these methods generally produce a new page as well

Comment: You could try the `fewerfloatpages` package but in general please always supply a small but complete test file that shows the problem.

Comment: It would be a good idea to check the float that starts the deferral to see if there is a reason -- maybe it's too large for the space allowed at top or bottom of a page and you didn't include a "p" specification in your placement options.  (That's the most frequent cause for deferring floats that I know of.)  There may be a message in your log file.

Comment: If you are using Plain TeX or OpTeX then you can use `\vfill\supereject` before pages with the bibliography list.

Comment: Just a comment to say that I am having exactly the same problem, and the "fewerfloatpages" package doesn't solve it.

Comment: Other related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276408/floatbarrier-starting-a-new-page https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73778/figure-appears-in-bibliography https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/119

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but when I tried to add a comment nothing happened.

I tried a short MWE

```
 %bibprob.tex  SE 625388

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Some text. \cite{author-book}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the bibliography did not start a new page. Please provide a MWE that actually shows your problem.